# Temporal average of a data Matrix

Tags: matlab, mean, reshape

Lets image there is a 24x5 Matrix M with 1 hour data (24 values each) of 5 different variable types.

I like to average the data to e.g. 4-hour means.

Is there a better way to do it then with three reshapes like this?

```
M = reshape( nanmean( reshape( reshape(M,1,[]), 4, [] ) ), [], 5)
```

Or maybe better to read:

```
M = reshape(M,1,[]);
M = reshape(M,4,[]);
M = nanmean(M);
M = reshape(M,[],5);
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? It could be simplified to `nanmean(reshape(M, 4, 6, []), 1)`

Comment: I think it is not wrong, but for me it looked a little bit unskilledly coded (like toing and froing :) I like your approach with squeeze, thanks for this advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reshape` is not a costly operation in MATLAB since it only changes how data is addressed and doesn't touch or copy the underlying data.

That being said, you only really need one call to `reshape`.

```
means = squeeze(nanmean(reshape(M, 4, 6, []), 1))
```